# Switchable Graphics in ubuntu[18.10]

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, switchable-graphics

I have AMD RADEON graphics in my laptop. As I was using windows 10, I had inbuilt as well as *third party* softwares for switching between intel and Amd graphics for different applications/games. Is there similar software available for Ubuntu? Even Amd website is not giving proper software for switching for Ubuntu as it was giving Crismon tool on windows.
[image: Amd Switchable Graphics]

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is add `DRI_PRIME=1` before the command of whatever you want to run using your dedicated Radeon GPU, so for example you can run Steam using `DRI_PRIME=1 steam`, and all of you games should use the Dedicated GPU.

If that does not work, then you might need to install `switcheroo-control` (I had to do that too) using `sudo apt install switcheroo-control`. This will also add an option to run using dedicated GPU from the right-click drop down menu in GNOME, so for example you can choose the dedicated GPU for Steam from the application menu > right-click Steam > "Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card":

[image: dedicated GPU option in GNOME]

If your steam games still use the integrated GPU after all of that (which they shouldn't), then you might need to enter `DRI_PRIME=1 %command%` to each game in their Launch Options. More on that [here.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947)

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on a HP G72 w/ Intel/Radeon (HD 5430/5450/5470) setup.

First, what do you mean by `DRI_PRIME=1` ? Do you mean it must be added to the command line ? For instance `firefox DRI_PRIME=1` ?

Then, I tried to use `switcheroo-control`, but to no avail. I installed it with `apt`, but nothing changed, no added option in favorite dock (right-side of the screen application icons). Do I need to reboot, change some config file, or anything else ?

Thanks for any hint ^-^

Comment: The command need to be **prefixed** by `DRI_PRIME=1` !!!!

For instance, if you want to run `glxgears` with the dedicated graphics (AMD or NVidia depending on the machine) instead of the integrated one (usually Intel), type : `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears`

Comment: Thanks Tooniis for this answer, I've been trying to use my dGPU for months to no avail and now it works !  However, it took me nearly one hour to figure that DRI_PRIME was a kind of directive to be typed **before** the command ^-^

Comment: @Mutos the example I provided is clear isn't it? Anyway, I edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @Mutos you need to enable the `switcheroo-control` service first. Either reboot, or `sudo systemctl enable --now switcheroo-control` to enable it. Enabling without rebooting might require a session restart (log out then back in), although I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Hi Tooniis, now it's very clear with the screenshot ^-^ I now have got the "Launch using dedicated graphics card" item on the menus, for instance freeCAD. And of course, I can launch with DRI_PRIME=1 the most important app, that is, the game I'm TCing ^-^